# Where is Rakudo x86 32-bit precompiled installer/binaries?

Tags: 32-bit, raku, rakudo

I would like to write my program using Perl6/Rakudo and it must run on both 32-bit and 64-bit OSes (Windows and Linux).

But 32-bit Rakudo installer will not released any more.

What is the best I can do to get working 32-bit Rakudo Star installer?

Answer (score 4):

> But 32-bit Rakudo will not released any more.

Rakudo itself is not 64-bit only and it's tested against supported Ubuntu 32-bit distributions before release.

If you need 32-bit Linux packages (Ubuntu), you'll find them here: https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg.

32-bit Windows binaries you'll have to build yourself from source: https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg.

However, be aware that 32-bit Rakudo is not JIT enabled and can be significantly slower than 64-bit.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "Rakudo Star 32-bit installer (binaries)" instead of simply "Rakudo 32-bit" in my question. 
And more questions: 
why there is no precompiled 32-bit Windows binaries by rakudo.org team?
why 32-bit is not JIT enabled?

Comment: All of the precompiled packages are built by volunteers.  There is no volunteer known to have the toolchain needed to build on WIn32.  If you are one, then please submit your binary builds for download by others.  As to why 32-bit not being JIT enabled: the JIT currently only supports 64bit Intel machine codes. Again, there is no one available willing to do the work to support 32bit Intel machine opcodes.  Or for othet processors such as ARM.  Again, if you want to help with such an effort, let yourself be known!

Answer (score 2):

If a compiler release, in other words not a star release, is enough for you, I offer an unofficial 32bit windows build of rakudo here: https://perl6.org/~timo/

Please be aware that I explicitly do not guarantee that it works. I have very little windows knowledge, and whenever I make a build, I have to RDP into a container offered by AppVeyor.